# how to solve system of congruence with multivariables

Tags: congruences, algebraic-equations

There `n` variables **x1,x2,...,xn** represented as **X**, `n` equations whose coefficient matrix (n*n) is represented as **A**, and this system looks like this:

**AX = B (mod k)**

Initially I was trying to solve this system using ordinary **Gaussian Elimination**, can't seem to get right solution.

Can't I just apply ordinary **Gaussian Elimination** here on system of congruence?  What is the right way to solve it?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k$ is a prime number, Gaussian Elimination in the finite field $F_k$ works as usual.

In other cases, one considers $A$ as a matrix with integral coefficients. You put it in Smith normal form : that is $A$ is equivalent to a matrix $A'$, with $A'$ having only diagonal coefficients $(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n)$ with $d_i$ dividing $d_{i+1}$.

Write $A = PA'Q$ with $P,Q$ invertible and computable. Your system is just $A'(QX) = P^{-1}B$ (mod $k$) because for an invertible $P$ and $C$ a column vector, $C$ has coefficients divisible by $k$ if and only if $PC$ has coefficients divisible by $k$. In this way, you find immediately the eventual solution $QX$, hence $X$.

You can also use Hermite normal form.

Comment: Why should **k** be prime? What if it's not? Could you please show me some concrete examples?

Comment: Smith and Hermite normal forms work over the integers. You can find a lot of examples by googling it. 

Comment: Thanks, I'm just having a time figuring out why Gaussian Elimination works only when k is prime. 